# BLOGGER Emporio give color based on label

Tags: blogger, blogger-dynamic-views

In Homepage trying to give color .feed-view .post-wrapper .snippet-thumbnail-container based on label. For example for label "Italiano" background-color:red and for label "English" background-color:blue,

```
<b:if cond='data:view.isHomepage'><style>.feed-view .post-wrapper .snippet-thumbnail-container{background-color:red!important}</style></b:if>
```

with this code all thumbnails get red in Homepage but when i add label condition ...

```
<b:if cond='data:view.isHomepage and data:post.labels any (l =&gt; l.name == &quot;Italiano&quot;)'><style>.feed-view .post-wrapper .snippet-thumbnail-container { background-color: red !important}</style></b:if>
```

with this code no color at all.
My mistake is in condition post.labels but i can't find exactly what is the the mistake.

At the end only my Home Page should look like this:
[image]

Comment: can you provide more code, where did you put this?

Comment: This code was put at the end just before </body>. I tried with loop also but same result. isHomepage would color snippets in Homepage but labels wont work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search the theme for the below code (it may appear more than once, you can update them all, or keep testing until find the one you need to update):

```xml
<b:includable id='postWrapperClasses'>
  <b:class cond='data:post.featuredImage' name='image'/>
  <b:class cond='not data:post.featuredImage' name='no-image'/>
  <b:class cond='data:post.labels and not data:post.labels.empty' name='has-labels'/>
</b:includable>
```

And add this line to it, this will set a custom class if the post contains a label you choose.

```xml
<b:class cond='data:post.labels any l => l.name == "Italiano"' name='SOME-CLASS'/>
```

Then you can customize it using css

```css
.SOME-CLASS .snippet-thumbnail-container {
    background: red !important;
}
```

Comment: Maybe my post is not clear. I already explained that i tried loop with same results. Maybe it will be easier to check the website. Is Kritere.com and since they don't use images in their posts i'm trying to give a color IN HOMEPAGE to each .post-outer (each post container in feed) based on label. Please check also image added to post to make it more clear.

Comment: It works. Thank you